# Using a Progress bar and a click counter

Tags: c#, forms, button, click, progress-bar

I'm using a windows form in c#.

So my question is as follows, in my form I have a button. And a progress bar.

How do I make it so that the progress of the bar relates to the number of clicks the user does on a button?

(In other words, the user clicks the button and the progress of the bar goes up.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? How didn't (or did) it work? What problems do you have with your code? And if you haven't tried it yet, then please do so first. If you have specific problems with your code then you're welcome back here to ask about that specific problem.

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: I have, I saw several ways of getting the progress bar to work, and to count the clicking of the button. Not to actually relate the two.
(bare in mind I'm as new to c# as you can be);
As far as my code goes, i have nothing except for the form design and it's respective empty code.

Comment: Are you new to .Net in general? Are you familiar with variable scope? Have a look on MSDN for the docs on ProgressBar, you may see a property you'd like to change for each click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (progressBar1.Value < progressBar1.Maximum)
        progressBar1.Value++;
}
```

But note, you cannot set `Value` to a higher number than `Maximum`

Comment: No Problem. It would be great if you accept the answer.